# Layer Images in java

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to layer these two images, but only one of them are displaying. Help please :).

```
public void loadImage() {



           JPanel imgPane = new JPanel();
  img = new JLabel(bg, JLabel.CENTER);
  imgPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  imgPane.add(img);// center
  panel1.add(imgPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);// background image (center)
  gameFrame.add(panel1);


  JPanel imgPane1 = new JPanel();

        img1 = new JLabel(bg1, JLabel.CENTER);
  imgPane1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  imgPane1.add(img1);// center
  panel1.add(imgPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);// background image (center)
  gameFrame.add(panel1);


 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the image path is correct? Have you tried making a simple example with just a JFrame and your image?

Comment: `public ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon("sword.png");` 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) Once there is an URL, use `ImageIO.read(URL)` to load it, for lots of helpful info. if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file path is relative to the working directory. For example, if your file path is `sword.png` then the image must have the same parent folder as `src`. For example:

[image]

Try moving your image to the root of your project folder, I've verified that it works.

By the way, you can test whether or not a file exists using this simple line of code:

```
System.out.println(new File("sword.png").exists());
```

This will tell you if the file exists relative to the working directory. In your case, this will be false. If your image is in the your `src` directory then use the path `src/sword.png`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.